# How to get all elements out of multiple List<>?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0, linq-to-objects

In C#, I have the following types:

```
List<List<mytype>> MyLists;
List<mytype> MainList;
```

I would like to take each element in all List<> inside MyList and put them in MainList.  MainList will then have only elements composed of all elements that were inside each List<> of MyList.  I've tried the following but get an error about not being able to infer the type:

```
MyLists.ForEach(list => MainList.AddRange(list.SelectMany(x => x != null)));
```

I wasn't sure what to put in SelectMany() since I want all elements within the List<>.  Those elements don't need to meet any criteria.

Any suggestions how it can be done?

Comment: Do you want `MainList` to have the elements in the lists in `MyLists` *added* to it (that's what my answer does)? Or do you want `MainList` to consist *solely* of the elements from the lists in `MyLists`? In that case do what @Reed says

Comment: Also - If the null check is required, I added some options for that - I'm not 100% sure *which* list could contain null values, so I showed both options in my edit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MainList.AddRange(from list in MyLists
                  from element in list
                  select element);
```

Or, if you prefer,

```
MainList.AddRange(MyLists.SelectMany(list => list));
```

Comment: What about `x!=null` in the question?

Comment: So the problem was using `SelectMany` instead of `Where`? Just trying to learn

Comment: @Hemal: SelectMany "flattens" a sequence containing sequences (ie: `List<List<T>>` into one `IEnumerable<T>`) - Where is used to filter (ie: remove elements, such as those that are null).  They perform two distinctly different operations.

Comment: @Hemal: The solution should NOT include the null check.  The OP said "I wasn't sure what to put in SelectMany() since I want all elements within the List<>." In other words, he put that in because it was a required argument, not because he wanted to filter the list.

Comment: I think I understood. Thanks @Reed and phoog and Akash

Comment: @phoog I seem to be having a bad reading comprehension day today, thanks

Answer (score 3):

This just requires a single [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) call:

```
MainList = MyLists.SelectMany(l => l).ToList();
```

Note that this doesn't require constructing/initializing MainList prior to this call, as it's completely initialized from the `ToList()` call.

---

Edit:

Since you did include a `null` check, if you need to remove `null` elements from within your list, you could add that check, as well:

```
MainList = MyLists.SelectMany(l => l.Where(i => i != null)).ToList();
```

And/Or filter for entire `null` lists:

```
MainList = MyLists
             .Where(l => l != null)
             .SelectMany(l => l.Where(i => i != null))
             .ToList();
```

Also, if you want to *add* items to your `MainList`, as opposed to making `MainList` "have only elements" in the original lists, you could use `AddRange` still:

```
MainList.AddRange(MyLists.SelectMany(l => l));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, closer to your original attempt: `MyLists.ForEach(list => MainList.AddRange(list));`

In other words, you don't need SelectMany or even Select if you are using ForEach and AddRange.